# Laravel : How can I use other database table in join?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5.3

I was unable to use other database table in my laravel project.
I did R & D to find the answer and face difficulty!
After resolving I thought to put it on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Open Config/database.php
Add
    'options'   => [ \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true ],
 in mysql section.
Resultant will be like this

```
'mysql' => [
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DB'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'strict' => true,
'engine' => null,
'options'   => [ \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true ],
],
```

Enjoy using other database table in join!